# Cannot open https site when Fiddler is opening

Tags: https, fiddler

I want to capture the https traffic using Fiddler, however when I open the Fiddler, the https site cannot be display. It works well when I close the Fiddler. Is there any setting to protected this please?

Comment: Fiddler is a MITM proxy, and it generates its own self-signed certificate to complete the connection with the client.  Make sure your HTTPS client is not rejecting Fiddler's certificate.  When Fiddler is running, it updates the proxy settings of WinInet so all WinInet-based apps, like Internet Explorer, tunnel through it automatically. For non-WinInet apps, they have to connect to Fiddler explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. The "Https client", do you mean the https site? Yes, when Fiddler is running, it updated my IE proxy setting to 127.0.0.1:8888, but I can capture the same https site on other machine, but it display nothing when I running the fiddler on this machine. I am not sure what's the different setting of browser or security?

Comment: Do you think the IE browser setting or security setting may cause this problem please?

Comment: no, the "https client" is the browser, the site is the "https server".

Comment: How can I make sure my IE browser not reject the Fiddler self-signed certification, and how can I verify this issue is caused by cert rejecting please?

Answer (score 0):

> the https site cannot be display

What *exactly* happens in the browser (and which browser was it)?

What do you see in Fiddler in this case, both in the Web Sessions list and in Fiddler's `Log` tab?